# Does my iPhone app have to work on iPad too?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I was reading the apple guidelines are there is a point which says

> iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Does this mean if my app doesn't work perfectly fine on an iPad, it gets rejected? I'm posting this here as I found many contradicting information regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it has to *run*, not that it has to be *optimized* for iPad.

There is a big difference in that. You don't have to create iPad storyboard in order to make app run on an iPad - Xcode lets iPad use the iPhone storyboard and open it as if it was an iPhone. The view is then shrunk into a smaller rectangle.

You are aiming for something like this:

[image]

Comment: Suppose there are layout issues when running on iPad. Say the app layout gets messed up. Is this a cause of worry ? Aren't there lots of iPhone specific apps ?

Comment: You can run an iPhone App on an iPad. It look different.

Comment: It shouldn't be messed up. It should look like the iPhone version but simply taking up smaller space on the screen.

Comment: What if I use code to generate my UI and no storyboards are involved ? Sorry for the nagging totally new to this.

Comment: Then check if you don't have your project set up as "Universal". Because if you do, then it will generate the UI differently on iPad

Answer (score 2):

Apple has build Xcode in way that when you build and iphone app, it will also be compatible for iPads with 1x and 2x resolution. So you need not worry about creating a separate storyboard for iPad. Hope you find this helpful. Happy coding !

Comment: What if storyboards are not used ? All my UI will be created using code without using .nib files or storyboards

Comment: Need not worry it would work just fine if it works good without any UI layout problems on your iPhone.